# HTML Text is randomizing position in Owl-Carousel divs

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, owl-carousel

I'm not sure it is Owl-Carousel but my text is all weirding out. 
This is how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C03TL.jpg

And this is HTML Code:

```
<div class="panel panel-casestudy" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 258px;">
<h4><strong>200% wzrost sprzedaży</strong></h4>
<p>W ciągu 2 lat współpracy sprzedaż wzrosła dwukrotnie, czyli z 40 tysięcy złotych miesięcznie na ponad 80 tysięcy złotych miesięcznie. </p>
<p><a href="/artykul/25,case-study.html">Czytaj więcej...</a></p>
```

As you can see in HTML 200% should be first word. And dots are on left side instead of ending of text.

I'm using Zurb Foundation Framework, Owl-Carousel-2 and and data-equalizer from foundation to make it all same size.

Please help.

Comment: It looks as though the attribute `dir="rtl"` is set somewhere. If it's there, try removing it.

Comment: No it's not set anywhere. It's first time I see this problem though.

Comment: In that case, there's not enough code here to make a diagnosis. Could you try re-creating the problem in a JSFiddle and post the link in your question.

Comment: I will try. But do you know anything that could do something like this?

Comment: Dayum it was rtl in my carousel. I din't looked there and copied from image slider when I wanted one to go other way :) Thanks man. This is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6zhoj0o5/1/ ad it as a anwear

Comment: Glad to help you out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new instance of your carousel, you set the `rtl` property to true.

Change the JQuery to:

```
$(".historiesukcesu").owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    autoplay:true,
    stagePadding: 50,
    rtl:false,
    autoplayTimeout:3000,
    margin:0,
    smartSpeed:800,
    nav: false,
    dots: false,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        }
    }
});
```